# Consumable InApp purchase for different amount of product

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have a game where user can buy consumable product (i.e.: energy). Now, i want to start a SALE where i would sell MORE energy for the same amount of money (and probably different amount of energy, depending on user stats). Do i need to create new product ids for every possible amount of energy i sell, or i can use the same product? Is there any rules against this practice?

PS: Technicly i don't care either way - all user's data are saved on server and app purchases processed server-side. It's just a matter of time for apple to approve new products and some flexibility is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is possible. Reading from [Overview of In-App Purchase](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html):

> Although non-consumable products may be recovered using the built-in capabilities of Store Kit, non-renewing subscriptions must be restored by your server. You are responsible for recording information about non-renewing subscriptions and restoring them to users. Optionally, consumable products could also be tracked by your server. For example, if your consumable product is a service provided by your server, you may want the user to retrieve the results of that request on multiple devices.

So it seems you should be good as long as you save all info about purchase for future reference.